# Azure AD B2C Sign-Up Flow Not Sending DOB Attribute to API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am currently working with Azure AD B2C and having an issue where the DOB attribute is not being sent during the sign-up user flow to our API. I've already enabled the DOB attribute in the user flow.

Here's the JSON being sent to our API:

```
{
  "step": "PostAttributeCollection",
  "client_id": "...",
  "ui_locales": "en-US",
  "streetAddress": "...",
  "email": "sample@domain.com",
  "surname": "Doe",
  "givenName": "John",
  "identities": [
    {
      "signInType": "emailAddress",
      "issuer": "overcloudairwaysorg.onmicrosoft.com",
      "issuerAssignedId": "sample@domain.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

What's peculiar is that the DOB does appear in the output claims in the JWT token:

```
{
  "alg": "RS256",
  "kid": "X5eXk4xyojNFum1kl2Ytv8dlNP4-c57dO6QGTVBwaNk",
  "typ": "JWT"
}.{
  "ver": "1.0",
  .
  .
  .
  "extension_dateOfBirth": "1994-02-25",
}.[Signature]
```

I've checked the following things:

- DOB is included in the sign-up and sign-in user flow.
- Our client application is correctly set up to handle the DOB
  attribute.
- Users are entering their DOB during registration.

Despite all of this, the DOB is still not being sent. Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!